# Using thread Executors in SWT?

Tags: java, multithreading, swt, threadpool, executorservice

Is there a way to manage (start/stop) threads using executors / threadpools from within an SWT app? The threads will need to update back the UI thread so that changes can be reflected when / as they are done. Is that possible? The `Display.asyncexec()` only takes a runnable thread as an option, so I'm not sure how to best accomplish this.

Comment: The `Runnable` used by `Display.asyncExec` is not a thread it is an ordinary class so you can use this from a background thread.

Comment: @greg-449 what about executionservice?

Comment: I am not aware of any restrictions on `Display.asyncExec` use.

Comment: @greg-449 But you can only pass a runnable to it. How would I pass an `Executor` to it?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a `Runnable` to do what you want in your thread:

```
Display.getDefault().asynchExec(new Runnable() {
    public void run()
    {
       ... Code to update UI here
    }
});
```

Comment: Not good enough, I need to start multiple threads and need to be able to stop them at any time...

Comment: You use the `asyncExec` call in your background thread to update the user interface. `asyncExec` does **not** create a thread.